# Can I calculate an average height from a contour dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.2

Basically I have a contour dataset and need to find the average height.. seems simple but I cannot seem to find an answer.

Secondly... I am trying to find the average height of selected area within the dataset. so far I have selected the area with the  select tool and viewing selected attributes on the attributes table. Can I calculate the average of the selected contour lines in the attributes table? E.g. calculate average of a selected field?

Answer (score 1):

You can, just right-click on the field heading for the field you're interested in in the attribute table and click "Statistics". It will tell you the maximum, minimum, mean, and several other things for any numeric field. If you have certain rows selected, the statistics will be calculated for those rows only.

However, doing that for a set of contour lines in a certain area won't necessarily get you an accurate result for the average elevation in that area. For that, you'd need to get a hold of a digital elevation model (DEM) of the area. A set of contour lines only gives you elevations for the exact points the lines pass through. A DEM gives you elevations across the entire area.

Comment: Brilliant! I knew there was a simple way. I don't need it to be too accurate at the moment so that should do the trick. Thanks very much!!